# java future with runnable, not just callable

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

Can Runnables be used with Future? Or just Callables?  I would like to use the isDone() and cancel() method of Future, but would like to use a ThreadPoolExecutor which only takes Runnable.

Comment: What does the [ExecutorService API say](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-)?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Apparently it says to ask the question here ;)

Answer (score -1):

> Can Runnables be used with Future?

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-) summary for `ExecutorService`:

> `Future<?> submit(Runnable task)` - Submits a Runnable task for
>   execution and returns a Future representing that task.
>
> `<T> Future<T> submit(Runnable task, T result)` - Submits a Runnable
>   task for execution and returns a Future representing that task.

---

> ... but would like to use a ThreadPoolExecutor which only takes Runnable.

According to the javadocs, a `ThreadPoolExecutor` has `submit`  methods that take both `Runnable` and `Callable`.

Read the javadocs for more details.

---

In short:

1. Yes they can.
2. Your (apparent) concerns about not being able to submit `Callable` tasks to a `BoundedExecutorService` are unfounded.